# Pyinstaller to OpenCV problem. Facial Emotion Recognition

Tags: python, opencv

Ok so, I'm developing a facial expression recognition app using Python. I was exporting the Python backend in a Tkinter GUI. Testing the app using the cmd and the python app.py it all works.
The issue happens when I convert the app.py in an exe file using Pyinstaller. When I run the app I get this error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-i1s8y2i1\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

I don't understand why I get this problem only in the exe file :/

Comment: This error is mainly due to not loading the image correctly; maybe when you compiled the app you changed some directories, how are you passing the photo to your App?

Comment: I use the webcam. I'm not using any images

Comment: Was your webcam being used by another script or another program when you tried to open it? This error means the .exe you're producing has problems accessing the webcam.

Comment: No, the webcam works correctly when I run a sample OpenCv file and try to convert it. I saw that the path C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-i1s8y2i1\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp doesn't even exists on my PC... I don't why the app is using it.